# Google GCM MismatchSenderID

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to make a simple push notification test app and I can't seem to be able to figure out the right credentials to use.

Given what I've found, my belief is that all I need is a PushNotification server key, api project number and the device's registration ID. I got my server key from the Google Dev console:
[image]

My project API number from here in the Console:
[image]
Which is incidentally the number after "project=api-project-" in my dashboard URL.

And lastly, the device registration ID that I got from an InstanceID object:

```
var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance (this);
var token = instanceID.GetToken (
                        "68********12", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
SendRegistrationToAppServer (token);
Subscribe (token);
```

Altough I believe the app never gets to the point where the GCM tries to send the message to the app, I believe the issue resides between teh app that sends the message and teh GCM server. That's all I need is it not?

As far as the code that sends the push messages to the app (the one notifyong me of the errror), I'm using the PushSharp library v3. The code looks something like this:

```
List<string> registrationIDs = new List<string> ();
registrationIDs.Add ("APA*************************************HnHb");
var config = new GcmConfiguration ("AIza**********w8");
var broker = new GcmServiceBroker (config);


broker.OnNotificationFailed += (GcmNotification notification, AggregateException exception) => {
    exception.Handle(ex => {
        /*Ex handling*/

        return true;
    });
};

broker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) => {
    Console.WriteLine ("Notification Sent!");
};
broker.Start ();
string message = "";
while (message != "quit"){
    Console.Clear ();
    Console.WriteLine ("Message to be sent (\"quit\" to quit):\n");
    message = Console.ReadLine ();
    broker.QueueNotification (new GcmNotification () {
        RegistrationIds = registrationIDs,
        Notification = JObject.Parse ("{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"badge\":7}")
    });
}
broker.Stop ();
```

It would be in that `broker.OnNotificationFailed` line that I'm getting the `MismatchSenderID` from the GCM server. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: What are you using to generate the InstanceID token?

Comment: The project id number

Comment: I meant what library?

Comment: I'm coding in Xamarin which maps all the Android code to C#, so technically I'm using the standard Android code. So my understanding is that I'm using this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID

Comment: Generally MismatchSenderID indicates that the API key you are using to send messages to the device is from a different project than the one you used to generate the InstanceID token. Could you confirm that the API key used in GcmConfiguration is from the same project with id used in GetToken

Comment: sadly I can't physically check right now but I have access to the Google console where the screens where taken. The InstanceID token was generated with the number that I see as I land in the dashboard under Project number (682....12). And in that same console I can navigate to API manager > Credentials > PushNotKey1 and I see the AIza****w8 key that I used in the GcmConfiguration. Can the server key not belong to the API project?